# Strike through java.awt.Font

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way to make a java.awt.Font strike through?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

So i found this, which works.

```
Font font = new Font("helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 12);
Map  attributes = font.getAttributes();
attributes.put(TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH, TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH_ON);
Font newFont = new Font(attributes);
```

Comment: would you know why I get a raw type error with your exact code?

Comment: @DhruvErry You might have had your IDE create the `attributes` variable, which might have declared it as a `<TextAttribute, ?>` where the `?` causes the problem. You need to declare the `Map` without any type specifiers.

Answer (score 6):

underline and strikethrough examples in awt.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/TextAttributeUnderlineandstrikethrough.htm

Basically, create a new AttributedString out of your string, add a STRIKETHROUGH attribute, and draw.

NOTE: This will NOT make the FONT strikethrough, but you can set the text to that font and then strikethrough on the text. This is simply another way of doing it. Rich's answer actually makes the font strikethrough.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are interested in what other text attributes are available you can use the [Visual Font Designer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/30/visual-font-designer) to experiment with different attributes to see how they look. The designer also allows you to change the Font so you can verify if the strike through is available for the Font you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
yourTextView.setPaintFlags(holder.name.getPaintFlags() |
Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```