# Strikethrough a node in a JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree, strikethrough, treecellrenderer

In my project i have a Jtree with custom node (which extends DefaultMutableTreeNode). Each node is associated with a boolean value. When the boolean is False i woul like to strike the texte of my node. So for example :

- node 1

  - node1.1
  - <strike>node1.2</strike>
- node 2

  - node2.1
  - ...

I tried to create a new Font but i don't find any properties to strike the text and i only managed to add my custom font to the whole tree and not node by node.

I think that i should use the TreeRenderer but i can't find any method to help me strike the node.

Does someone have an idea on i can do it ?

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070878/strike-through-java-awt-font might help. You need to write a `TreeCellRenderer` though.

Comment: Works perfectly, Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the example below. For keeping it simple, I am just striking through the selected node. You need to, of course, use your own check on the value.

```
package snippet;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer;

public class JTreeTest extends JFrame {
    private final class StrikeoutCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean sel, boolean expanded,
                boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
            Component c = super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
            Font font = c.getFont();
            Map attributes = font.getAttributes();
            if(sel)
                attributes.put(TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH, TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH_ON);
            else
                attributes.remove(TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH);
            Font newFont = new Font(attributes);
            c.setFont(newFont);
            return c;
        }

    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public JTreeTest() {
        super(JTreeTest.class.getName());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        JTree tree = new JTree();
        tree.setCellRenderer(new StrikeoutCellRenderer());
        add(tree);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                JTreeTest t = new JTreeTest();
                t.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note that even if the node doesn't need a strike through, you need to reset the attribute, since a single component is used for painting all the nodes.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to define a renderer (extending `DefaultTreeCellRenderer`) and call `setText()` passing html string like this "`<html><u>node1.2</u></html>`" as value for the strikethrough.